# Sitecore with Solr search and Autosuggestion

Tags: jquery, solr, sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8.1

We have applied Solr Search with Sitecore 8.1 and MVC, where we are struggling with Auto complete/ Auto Suggestion functionality on Search Text box.

**Issue:**
Results are not appearing as fast as we expect. it is taking too much time.

**What we have did:**

A. We have created Ajax call on cshtml page like below.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#SearchQuery").autocomplete({
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 3,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@(Url.Action("SearchSuggestion", "SearchService"))",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { enteredText: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    response(data);
                }
            })
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: "", results: ""
        }
    });
})
```

B. This is our Controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SearchSuggestion(string enteredText, int? page)
    {
        var result = service.GetSearchAutoData(enteredText).ToList();
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public List<Search> GetSearchAutoData(string searchText)
    {
        var searchresult = GetSearchAutoSuggetions(searchText)
            .Take(10)
            .Select(x => new Search 
                { 
                    title = x.Document.GetItem().Name, 
                    description = x.Document.GetItem().Fields["Description"].ToString(), 
                    extenstion = x.Document["GetMediaExtension"], 
                    url = (x.Document.GetItem().Paths.IsMediaItem) ? Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(new MediaItem(x.Document.GetItem())) : x.Document.GetItem().Paths.ContentPath                         
                })
                .Where(x => (x.extenstion.ToLower() != "jpeg" && x.extenstion.ToLower() != "jpg" && x.extenstion.ToLower() != "png"));  
        return searchresult.ToList();
    }
```

So we want to optimize our code, or can anybody help to implement such scenario?

Comment: There could be many reasons - first what does this function do? `GetSearchAutoSuggetions`

Comment: This function helps me to get search result using Sitecore Content search API. Code as below

Comment: Ok - but that is probably the code that is going to be the bottle neck in performance. First does it return an `IQueryable` ?

Comment: 'public SearchResults<SearchHelper> GetSearchAutoSuggetions(string searchtext)
        {
            using (searchContext)
            {                               
                var query = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchHelper>().OrderByDescending(i => i.BoostingValue).Where(i => (i.MetaTitle.Contains(searchtext) || i.Name.Contains(searchtext)) &&
                    !i.IsStandardvalue && i.ShowInSearchResult == true ));
                var result = query.GetResults();
                return result;
            }
        }'

Comment: public IProviderSearchContext searchContext
        {

            get
            {
               // string indexName = string.Format("sitecore_{0}_index", Sitecore.Context.Database.Name);
                string indexName = string.Format("sitecore_web_index");
                var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(indexName);
                return index.CreateSearchContext();
            }
        }

Comment: Please add to the original question - its hard to read as a comment

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that I see is that `GetSearchAutoSuggestions` returns a `SearchResult` and you are then filtering and trimming down the results in memory. This means that the bulk of the data is going to be returned from the index and all the deserialization will be done on a potentially large dataset.

You should either change that function to return an `IQueryable<SearchResult>` or do the filtering and `.Take(10)` inside that method.

Some potential changes:

```cs
public SearchResults<SearchHelper> GetSearchAutoSuggetions(string searchtext, int maxResults)
{
    using (searchContext) 
    { 
        var query = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchHelper>()
            .OrderByDescending‌​(i => i.BoostingValue)
            .Where(i => (
                i.MetaTitle.Contains(searchtext) 
                || 
                i.Name.Contains(searchtext)
                ) 
                && !i.IsStandardvalue 
                && i.ShowInSearchResult == true
                && i.extenstion.ToLower() != "jpeg" 
                && i.extenstion.ToLower() != "jpg" 
                && i.extenstion.ToLower() != "png"
            ).Take(maxResults); 


        var result = query.GetResults(); 
        return result; 
    } 
}
```

This would move the filtering work to the index and only return the required records. Depending on how many the original filter returned, that could improve performance a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Will try it.

Comment: One more thing,

When i press enter on search textbox, it will redirect to search result page.  On that time it is taking too much time i.e. approx 8-9 second.
Will this approach help in that ? i guess i dont need to fetch .take(10) during that time
i need to fetch all the records. Right ?

Comment: You should open a new question for that - you might get some better support for that on http://sitecorechat.slack.com/

Comment: Sure. will do that